# Trying to make ANOVA

Tags: r

So I'm trying to create an ANOVA to determine the independence of a population variable. My data consists of multiple countries from 4 different regions.
This is what I've been trying:

```
aov(Region ~ 'Population in thousands (2017)',data = anova.data)
```

I think I'm doing it right but, every time I get:

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, "Error", data = data) : invalid term in model formula
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use backticks like "`" around your predictor.

Comment: @Skaqqs is correct, back-ticks are required for any series name that contains spaces.

Comment: Even with back-ticks, it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

`aov()` is expecting a `?formula`. In addition to being faster to type and read, this is why it is common practice to make variable names as short and simple as possible i.e., abbreviations with no spaces or special characters.

```
aov(Region ~ `Population in thousands (2017)`, data = df)

# easier
aov(Region ~ Population_in_thousands_2017, data = df)

# easiest
aov(Region ~ pop2017, data = df)
```

Comment: I tried that but now I'm getting this: Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

Comment: This doesn't seem related to your formula problem. Are there "NA/NaN/Inf" in `Region`?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out @Jack?